# How to create function and call function

Tags: php, html

Can anybody give me one example of creating a simple function which returns the sum of both the input fields?

```
<html>
  <body>
    number1:<input type="text" name="number1" />
    number2:<input type="text" name="number2" />
    <input type=submit name="submit" value="submit"/>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: can you edit your question with proper english?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function addition( $num1,$num2)
{

    echo "Result = " . $num1 + $num2;
}

and call the  function  by 


if(isset($_POST["submit"]))
{

  $num1=$_POST['number1'];
  $num2=$_POST['number2'];
addition( $num1,$num2);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I think this is what you are searching for:
http://php.net/manual/en/tutorial.forms.php

Answer (score 0):

try the following:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST))
{
    echo "Result = " . $_POST['number1'] + $_POST['number2'];
}
?>
<html>
<head>
<title> Example of the radio blur method</title>
</head>
<body>

<form name="form1">
<input type="text" name="number1" value="">
<input type="text" name="number2" value="">
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Add">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: saurabh its not print out put

Comment: @Nikunj Jagad: Please read what you have written in the question. I have replied accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Try;

```
<html>
<body>
<form action='<?php echo $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"] ?>' method='post'>
number1:<input type='text' name='number1'/>
number2:<input type='text' name='number2'/>
<input type='submit' name='submit' value='submit'/>
</form>
<br/>
<?php
if($_POST["submit"]){
   echo "$_POST[number1] + $_POST[number2] = ".($_POST["number1"] + $_POST["number2"])."<br/>\n";
}
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: No problem - hope your project goes well  :)